# Edge values of 2D Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-processing

I have a 2D Numpy array of the following form (up to 5000 rows):

```
 [ 247.68512  182.67136]
 [ 248.71936  182.67136]
 [ 249.74336  182.67136]
 [ 253.85984  269.1072 ]
 [ 254.89408  269.1072 ]
 [ 255.91808  269.1072 ]
 [ 249.74336  182.67136]
 [ 250.7776   182.67136]
 [ 251.8016   182.67136]
 ...
```

Where column 0 corresponds to x, and column 1 to y.

When plotted the data should resemble a blob shape.

[image: Example blob]

[image: Example blob2]

How can I reduce this data to just have the edge or contour around the blob?

I have looked at some of the skimage edge detection functions but I think there is a pure numpy solution out there.

Any help? If edge detection is the way to go what's the best tool?

Thanks

--- Edit ---- 
The data is also unsorted, but I can sort around the orgin of the blob with some existing code I have. Not sure if that helps.

[image: Sorted Blob Example]

--- Edit 2 --- 
Stumbled upon [this](http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2014/05/12/drawing-boundaries-in-python/) beautiful solution by K.D.

I think this should work perfectly for this application. Will try this.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the plot, but it looks like the points are very close to falling on a regular grid with a spacing of ~1 in X and Y. If you were to round each X and Y coordinate to the nearest integer value, would any of the points end up overlapping?

Comment: I added another plot to show the data a bit better. If I round each x,y to int there would definitely be overlap just due to the number of blob-points.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the topology of the blob. If the blob is smooth and has no voids inside you can do this:
approach blob from far. Scan across blob location. When you hit a point - check neighboring grid. If you have high enough point density set `isOnBorder = true`. Now, for each neighboring point check if it is such that it has both empty and filled neighbors. If yes - this is a border point - add it to list. Repeat procedure until you get full border. If you have voids you would have to do grid inside and check for inner borders as well.